# Импорт определенного класса из модуля на Python

Tags: python, импорт, класс

Столкнулся с непонятной для меня проблемой — при попытке импортировать один класс из какого-то модуля, у меня импортируется весь модуль.

То есть у меня есть модуль Pers.py:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def About(self):
        print("Helloo, i am {} {}!".format(self.name, self.surname))

Ignat = Person("Ignat", "Baranov")
Ignat.About()
```

Я захотел импортировать ТОЛЬКО класс Person, но при выполнении нового модуля, в котором я хотел использовать мой класс, у меня выполняется и та часть кода, где происходит создание объекта Ignat.

Это новый модуль:

```
from Pers import Person

Peter = Person("Peter", "Devidson")
Peter.About()
```

А результат выполнения такой:

```
Helloo, i am Ignat Baranov!
Helloo, i am Peter Devidson!
```

То есть можно ли как-то из модуля импортировать ТОЛЬКО нужный мне класс, без выполнение других его частей??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def About(self):
        print("Helloo, i am {} {}!".format(self.name, self.surname))

if __name__ == '__main__':                  # <---
    Ignat = Person("Ignat", "Baranov")
    Ignat.About()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Хотелось бы уточнить кое-что: строчка `if __name__ == '__main__':` означает условие соответствия места выполнения файла?? То есть если запустить Pers.py, то создание объекта произойдет, а если этот модуль будет импортирован куда-то, то нет??

Comment: @ilovesnikers да, вы все правильно поняли.